# Elastic Search Create Index - Failed

Tags: elasticsearch, curl

> curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST 'https://mydomain/' -d @cps_index.json

Contents in ths JSON file

```
{
"settings": {
    "mappings": {
        "_source": {
            "enabled": false
        },
        "cps": {
            "properties": {
                "firstName": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "lastname": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "email": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "mobileNumber": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "employeeId": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Failed with the Response Message *{"error":"Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/] and method [POST], allowed: [GET, HEAD, DELETE]","status":405}***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues:

- no index name
- use PUT instead of POST
- `mappings` is nested into `settings`

Do this instead:

Modify cps_index.json like this:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "_source": {
                "enabled": false
            },
            "properties": {
                "firstName": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "lastname": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "email": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "mobileNumber": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "employeeId": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Run this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPUT 'https://mydomain/indexname'
                                           ^                        ^
                                           |                        |
                                        use PUT              add index name
```

Comment: I'm using 6.5 Version, When I use the above json. It still throws an error. Instead I used this and it worked {
 "mappings": {
  "_doc": {
            "_source": {
                "enabled": false
            },
   "properties": {
    "firstName": {
     "type": "text"
    },
    "lastName": {
     "type": "text"
    },
    "email": {
     "type": "text"
    },
    "mobileNumber": {
     "type": "keyword"
    },
    "employeeId": {
     "type": "keyword"
    }
   }
  }
 }
}

Comment: Yes, my bad, _source gores inside the mapping type. Fixed

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the index name after https://mydomain

```
https://mydomain/indexname
```

Comment: I did that and i received this error *{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  ......,"status":400}*

Comment: Looks like it expects some type name. But since ES deprecating the type. I don't want to use type. What can I do here. Thanks